# How to Insert A List of Posts in A Category Written by the Author into the Author Archive

Tags: functions, filters, author, categories

What I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4VAt.png (sorry for linking out, I am a new user here so can't post an image inline)

How does one list posts by an author within a category, with a count for each category, on the author archive page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most efficient way but it works, put this in your theme's functions.php

```
function author_post_breakdown($author_id){
    //get all post of this author
    $n = get_posts(array(
        'author' => $author_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
        )
    );
    $cats= array();
    //loop over all post of this author and get the categories for each post
    foreach((array)$n as $id){
        $cs = wp_get_object_terms($id, 'category');
        //loop over each category of the post and add the counter
        foreach($cs as $c){
            if (isset($cats[$c->slug])){
                $cats[$c->slug]['count'] = $cats[$c->slug]['count'] + 1;
            }else{
                $cats[$c->slug]['count'] = 0;
                $cats[$c->slug]['name'] = $c->name;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($cats as $sl => $arr)
        $retVal = '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($slug, 'category').'">'.$arr['name'].'('.$arr['count'].')</a></li>'; 

    return $retVal;
}
```

and in your author.php
add this:

```
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $_GET['author_name']) : get_userdata($_GET['author']);
echo '<ul>'.author_post_breakdown($curauth->ID).'</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks! When I added the function to the functions.php file, the site still ran swell.

However, when I added this to the author.php file, everything after wherever it was inserted wouldn't load on to the page in a browser (note the page would still load though, no 500 error or anything):

<?php $curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $_GET['author_name']) : get_userdata($_GET['author']); echo '<ul>'.author_post_breakdown($curauth->ID).'</ul>'; 
?>

Thanks again - seriously - and apologies if it's my user error with the added <?php ?> text somehow (is it?)

Comment: create a pastebin of your authors.php file